# Change in Itinerary - Any Problem in Future Applications?

Tags: indian-citizens, schengen-visas, multiple-entry

I am an Indian national who studied in the UK (2008-2009) and worked there for 3 years (2010-13) before coming to India in 2013. During this time I had traveled twice to Switzerland for business reasons in 2011 (Single Entry 7 days Visa) and 2012 (Multiple Entry 6 Months Visa)

I traveled again to Netherlands for tourism through France; had Dutch single entry visa for a month in May 2017. In Sep 2017, I had to travel to Italy and applied to Italian Consulate in Mumbai that I am travelling for Business reasons (got 1 month Multiple Entry Visa), however, plans got changed and I traveled to Italy (9 days) as well as Switzerland (5 days).

Meanwhile I traveled to Canada (Tourism and Business) Sep 2017, Singapore (Tourism) Feb 2018, and Dubai (Tourism) Dec 2017

I applied again for Schengen Visa in March 2018 and this time Netherlands gave me 1 Year Multi Entry Visa which I used only once in May 2018 valid till April 2019

I again traveled to Japan in July 2018, US in August 2018 and Canada in Sep 2018

Now I have to apply to Italian Consulate in New Delhi as my travel is from May 2019.

I have two questions: 
Does that minor change in itinerary in 2017 as I traveled to Switzerland for business reasons would have any effect on my current Schengen visa application?
Second, I had multiple entry visa for an year, but I used it only once to travel! Would they think I keep requesting Multi Entry Visas, but used them only once!

I am asking this as one of my mates made me scared! I am really anxious!

Answer (score 2):

> Does that minor change in itinerary in 2017 as I traveled to Switzerland for business reasons would have any effect on my current Schengen visa application?

It's very unlikely.  The problem with changes in plan arises when visa officers or border officers suspect that the original application was fraudulent.  But adding a short trip to Switzerland to a business trip in Italy doesn't smell of fraud, all the more so because with the change, you still spent more time in Italy than in Switzerland.

(Sometimes people submit fraudulent applications because they believe they are more likely to get a visa from a different country, so they make it look like that country is the main destination when in fact it is not.  In your case, the main destination of both your original itinerary and your modified itinerary is the same.)

> Second, I had multiple entry visa for an year, but I used it only once to travel! Would they think I keep requesting Multi Entry Visas, but used them only once!

I wouldn't worry too much about this one, either.  You've been receiving multiple entry visas because you are seen as a frequent and trustworthy traveler.  You will probably continue to be seen as such, so you will probably continue to receive multiple-entry visas.

> I am asking this as one of my mates made me scared!

If you can add some details of any stories you've heard that have contributed to your fear, we can perhaps highlight the factors that make these stories dissimilar to yours, if there are any.

Comment: (+1) In particular, it is not any _harder_ for a consulate to issue a multiple-entry visa than a single-entry one, so it is not as if anyone has any cause to think the OP has "wasted their time" or something such by requesting a multiple-entry visa and then only using it once.

Comment: Its just I told him that I am going to Italy again and he said last time I changed my itinerary  while I traveled to Italy and they will see I have changed it.....(This same guy told me that its illegal to travel on "Italian Schengen Visa" to Switzerland back in 2017)....I told him that I had traveled after that to Netherlands and they seems to be ok with it! If Italy had issue, wouldn't they have highlighted this in Visa Information System! He said VIS is only looked when you apply to Same Schengen Country....I just became anxious and started soughing answers from Internet....

Comment: @Sati10501: As your parenthetical remark shows, your friend doesn't know what he's talking about. Ignore him.

Comment: Thanks Henning....Its just I get anxiety from literally anything...and btw person is not a friend or a mate just a work acquaintance!

Comment: So I got my Schengen Visa from Italy today, however, only 30 days Multi Entry Visa.  I even showed that I need to travel again in October, but they anyhow decided to give me only 30 days Multi Entry. I already had 6 months - 1 year visa